# Why doesn't GCC optimize away memory writes in this summation loop?

Tags: c, gcc

Given the following C code, why does GCC (version 10.1, x86-64, -O3) write to memory inside the loop instead of just using two registers during summation and writing the result to memory only at the end?

```
void sum(unsigned int l, int *as, int *r) {
    r[0] = 0;
    r[1] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        r[0] += as[2 * i];
        r[1] += as[2 * i + 1];
    }
}
```

Generated instructions [here](https://godbolt.org/z/tusb2S).

My guess is that this behavior is related to GCC having concurrency "in mind". You could have another thread for example reading from memory at the same address while the summation is performed.
Is this the real (and only) reason? Is it probably even defined by a C standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler does not know whether `as` and `r` point into the same array, so it does not know that `r[0] += as[2 * i];` does not change the value of `as[2 * i + 1]`, which is needed in `r[1] += as[2 * i + 1];`, and similarly for other interactions between `r[0]`, `r[1]` and various elements of `as`.

You can tell the compiler that the elements referred to via `as` and `r` do not overlap by changing the function declaration to `void sum(unsigned int l, int * restrict as, int * restrict r)`.

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you!  
So the concurrency argument is not valid at all? If we wanted to have a different thread print out the current results at ```r``` every ```n``` seconds, would we have to explicitly tell the compiler not to optimize this?

Comment: @compilerdude: Yes, if you wanted to make the changing results of `*r` visible to another thread, you would have to declare it `volatile` or make other arrangements.

Comment: @compilerdude: Think of it this way: it could happen, by sheer bad luck, that your second thread gets scheduled out and doesn't get to run again until after the loop is completely finished.  So the system certainly isn't providing any guarantee that the thread would actually see the intermediate results.  Since nobody has been promised that they will be able to see the intermediate results, the compiler isn't under any obligation to actually store them.

Comment: In other words, the effect (for other threads) of waiting until the end to store the results is indistinguishable from something that could have already happened by chance (being scheduled out).  So it must be permissible for the compiler to do it.